# Is it possible to retrieve data using BusinessObjects SDK?

Tags: business-objects-sdk

Is it possible to retrieve data using BusinessObjects SDK? I have an application where I use BO opendocument service to get the charts generated. Is it possible to get the chart data using B SDK? Please advise.

Comment: Is this a WebI report?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the WebI RESTful SDK.  You have a couple of options: you can either retrieve the data from the data provider or export the data displayed in the report -- by "chart data" I'm guessing you're looking to the former, and retrieve the data provider data later transformed into a chart.  You should find the documentation you need to get started on SAP's web site.